# SQL IN Statement splitting parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server

I have a parameter that contains a comma delimited string:

> 'abc,def,ghi'

I want to use that string in a IN statement that would take my parameter like this:

```
select * from tableA where val IN ('abc','def','ghi')
```

Any ideas on how I would do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using dynamic SQL is an option, this can be executed:

```
SELECT 'SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE val IN (' +
       '''' + REPLACE('abc,def,ghi', ',', ''',''') + ''')'
```

Basically, the `REPLACE()` function separates each item by **','** instead of just **,**.

Comment: Is there a way to write this without it being dynamic?

Comment: @webdad3 Not that I know of - anyone else know of an option?

Comment: @webdad3 my solution works without creating dynamic SQL

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName
WHERE ',' + commaDelimitedString + ',' LIKE '%,' + FieldName + ',%'
```

But be careful about SQL injection. You might want to parameterize it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this SQL to 'pivot' a comma-separated string into a table;

```
DECLARE @badData TABLE (id INT NOT NULL, txt NVARCHAR(max));

INSERT INTO @badData
VALUES (1, 'foo,bar,baz'), (2, NULL);;

-- the idea is to recursively 'pop' a value from the start of the string, splitting it into 'head' and 'tail' components
WITH unpacked (id, head, tail)
AS (
  SELECT id, LEFT(txt, CHARINDEX(',', txt + ',') - 1), STUFF(txt, 1, CHARINDEX(',', txt + ','), '')
  FROM @badData

  UNION ALL

  SELECT id, LEFT(tail, CHARINDEX(',', TAIL + ',') - 1), STUFF(tail, 1, CHARINDEX(',', tail+ ','), '')
  FROM unpacked
  WHERE tail > ''
  )
SELECT id, head
FROM unpacked
ORDER BY id
```

You could stick this result into a common table expression, then write a where clause like

```
select * from tableA where val IN (select head from unpacked)
```

heavily plagiarised from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5493616/6722

Answer (score -3):

Many programming languages have a split() function, for example in Ruby

`'123,456,789'.split ","
=> ["123", "456", "789"]`

Comment: This answer is not relevant to the case here.