# Trying to use SQL Replace in a non-dynamic way

Tags: sql

I have the following statement, where I'm passing in a parameter like this:

> '0001,0003'

I was following the `REPLACE` answer from this question:
[SQL IN Statement splitting parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34099017/sql-in-statement-splitting-parameter)

But I'm trying to take it out of dynamic sql.  My returned result is `NULL`.  Is there anyway to get this to work?

```
DECLARE @partialLNum varchar(MAX)       
DECLARE @lNumConCat varchar(500)
DECLARE @tTemp table(lNum varchar(15))
DECLARE @formatIN varchar(MAX)

set @partialLNum = '0001,0003'
set @formatIN = ''''+ REPLACE(@partialLNum,',',''',''')+'''' 


        insert into @tTemp
        select substring(lNum,1,2) + '-' + substring(lNum,3,3) + '-' + substring(lNum,6,2) + '-' + substring(lNum,8,3)
        from  [rpt].[myView] 
        where LNum IN (@formatIN)


        select @lNumConCat =  COALESCE(@lNumConCat +'' , '', '''') + LNum from @tTemp
        select @lNumConCat
```

Comment: did you see http://stackoverflow.com/a/23438993/3664960

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`in` takes a list of values.  So:

```
    where LNum IN ('0001,0003')
```

has a list with one element, that happens to have a comment in it.

One way to do what you want is using `like`:

```
where ',' + partialLNum + ',' like '%,' + LNum + ',%'
```

There should suffice, but there are other ways using a `split()` function as well.